# PHP MYSQL DELETE FROM WHERE AND clause

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

Trying to get the following to work but for the life of me i cannot get this working.

Could someone assist?

```
DELETE FROM 'content' WHERE note_id = '7' AND WHERE userid = '1'
DELETE FROM 'note' WHERE id = '7' AND WHERE userid = '1'
```

I need to delete a record from each table where it checks that the user is actually that user but im getting syntax error when I run the query

I Receive the following when I remove the 2nd WHERE.

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntac to user near 'DELETE FROM `note` WHERE id ='7' AND userid = '1"
>   at line 2

Apologies turns out I added an extra space before the script got to here

Comment: there is no "WHERE" after AND

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only 1 `WHERE` needed, try this:

```
DELETE FROM content WHERE note_id = '7' AND userid = '1'
DELETE FROM note WHERE id = '7' AND userid = '1'
```

Comment: Ow, sorry, forgot to remove single quotes on tables them. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use single quotes around table names:

```
DELETE FROM `content` WHERE note_id = '7' AND userid = '1'
```

You have to use backticks around table and column names - not single quotes.

Also: You had two `where` in there - just use `and` between extra clauses.

Answer (score 3):

You've added multiple `WHERE` clauses in a single query, which will not work.

Try this:

`DELETE FROM content WHERE note_id = '7' AND userid = '1'`

`DELETE FROM note WHERE id = '7' AND userid = '1'`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DELETE FROM 'content' WHERE note_id = '7' AND userid = '1'
DELETE FROM 'note' WHERE id = '7' AND userid = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM content WHERE note_id = '7' AND userid = '1'
 DELETE FROM note WHERE id = '7' AND userid = '1'
```

Try this there were two errors, ' with table and where clause written twice